# What happens to Trick-or-Treat Bags after the Halloween event?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I've been farming for the past few days quit a few [Trick-or-Treats Bags](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Trick-or-Treat_Bag). I've been wondering if I should sell those now or wait until Halloween is over (since they won't drop anymore, their value should rise).

Will I be able to sell the bag after the event or do they become :

- Account bound ?
- Unusable ?
- Other ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Play around with the time sliders on the bottom of the graph at [spidy](http://www.gw2spidy.com/item/36038) and you'll notice the spike always tends to be a few days *before* Halloween starts. You'll also notice that, over time, there is a definite upwards trend of what people are willing to pay. So the best time to sell would probably be a little less than a year for now; the question is whether you'll want the stacks of these to take up valuable inventory space that long.

I've never heard of a case of items suddenly becoming account bound if they were previously tradeable. These bags are containers, so they won't become "unusable" either - you can always open them, though what's inside may become less useful after Halloween (or more annoying, as you end up with all these items taking up more inventory space after you've done your post-Halloween cleanup).

Answer (score 1):

My guess looking at the previous years is that you can still sell and use them. But in previous years so many people were hoarding the bags that the price was barely rising. Some items might no longer drop from those bags after the event though.